# statsmodels package code works in spyder's ipython console but not in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, spyder, statsmodels

This is a python script in the Spyder IDE of Anaconda. I have Python 3.6.2. The last two lines do nothing (apparently) when I run the script, but work if I type them in the IPython console of Spyder. How do I get them to work in the script please?

```html
# import packages
import os # misc operating system functions
import sys # system parameters and functions
import pandas as pd # data frame handling
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm # stats module
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # matlab-like plotting
import numpy as np # big, fast arrays for maths

# set working directory to here
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

# read data using pandas
datafile = '1314 Powerview Pasture Potential.csv'
data1 = pd.read_csv(datafile)
#list(data) # to show column names

# plot some data
# don't know how to pop out a separate window
plt.scatter(data1['long'],data1['lat'],s=40,facecolors='none',edgecolors='b')
             
# simple multiple regression
Y = data1[['Pasture and Crop eaten t DM/ha']]
X = data1[['Net imported Supplements per Ha',
                            'LWT/ha',
                            'lat']]
result = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
result.summary()
```

Comment: add a `print`, those commands do their work but don't show it. ipython shows some results automagically without print command.

Comment: The result variable does get created (it's some kind of wrapper) although it isn't visible in the Variable explorer.

Comment: ok print(result.summary()) works. Thanks. I was confused because for some reason the plot command shows the plot at the end of the output, with the old summary before it!